# How can I straighten a twisted necktie?

Tags: clothing

I have several neckties that twist at the end while I wear them.

Is there any way to straighten them? Would an iron straighten them out?

**UPDATE: ADDED PICTURES**

[image: Video]
[image: Picture]

Comment: It will be great if you provide some pictures for the same.

Comment: Iron it bro-dawg, it can be done!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIGAsIx7alM

Comment: Actually, I retract that last comment, and am in agreement with @maneeshmohan.  Without pictures of said neckties, this debacle may never get resolved.

Comment: @MANEESHMOHAN - pictures added

Comment: @digiliooo - pictures added

Answer (score 2):

Ironing may help but seeing the pictures I fear poorly made tie to start with.

If it was an expensive tie, bring it to the shop (or the chain of shops) you bought it.

When not returning them to the shop, check the washing information on the tie. If it is dry cleaning only, and you can not wear the tie as it is, try dry ironing.
If you can wash it, wash as per information label and iron.

In ironing, gently push it to get it flat again.

If the twist orginates from the knot with which you tie your tie, you can try a different knot and try to close it less tight.

And have you tried a tie pin to keep the tie in place even though it wants to turn?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way the necktie was assembled. You can ***fix*** it; but, the effort won't be worth it unless the tie has sentimental value. If you look at the back of your neck-tie you'll see the two sides of it are "tack-stitched" together where they meet. The bar-shape tack-stitch holds too securely to allow each side to "give" enough to lie flat after a few uses.
 Remove the tack-stitch and iron the tie and bunting inner liner; then, reassemble it: fold the sides together and baste them with a single thread rather than tack the sides.

You can ***avoid*** the problem by ensuring your neckties are "single thread." Single-thread neckties are folded lengthwise on either side to meet. A single thread is bast-stitched to either side to close the folded tie shut. The thread is not attached but allowed to just hang. The single thread gives your garment some "give" so asymmetrical knots don't twist the threads of the necktie. They are usually a bit more expensive because this cannot be automated. A person must finish the garment. Since it costs more anyway, better materials can be used as they are a smaller fraction (proportionally) of the cost of manufacture. Next time you find yourself in a mens store, ask the salesperson to show you the details of assembly.

You can ***hack*** the problem by fastening the tails of the necktie to your shirt with a tie-bar.

Some neck-ties have a loop for the smaller end to hold it in place behind the wider end. In addition, some have a series of button holes to attach to your shirt button.

Answer (score 0):

Iron it, You have to be careful though.

Comment: Because it will melt if you don't!

Comment: Could you add some more detail to this answer? It's been automatically flagged as low-quality.

Comment: @richard the same was told by previous answerer, better you update the answer or the same will get further more negative points

Answer (score 0):

I have to reccomend a [tie bar / tie clip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_clip) as the best solution to (reproducibly, and with minimum effort) solve your problem. There are plenty of cheap examples available online, and they can range from [quite plain and unobtrusive](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0158/1842/products/brushed-silver.jpg?v=1463679155) to the [slightly more gaudy examples](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/Tie_clips_wiki.jpg/200px-Tie_clips_wiki.jpg) shown on wikipedia.

(Credit to [Willeke's answer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/14921/7665), as they mentioned tie *pins* briefly.)